# How to .load() into the div that has the link to the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a dynamic site which loads the `div` content from other pages into the `div` content that has the links which use the function `.load()`. It works if the `div` you are changing is another `div` than the content `div`.

Here is the command that I think that should work:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="links">
        <a href="#" id="button">CLick here</a><br />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
          $("#button").on("click", function(){
            $("#container").load("example.php?q=2 #container > *");
          });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I replace `#container` with another `div`, the whole procedure works. But when I try to replace the container `div` it does absolutely nothing. In `example.php` there are some PHP functions which populate the inside of another div through MySQL.

How can I make the load function work on the upper `div`?

Comment: FYI [don't use jQuery-latest](http://blog.jquery.com/2014/07/03/dont-use-jquery-latest-js/).

Comment: Also this is confusing: *If I replace #container with another div, the whole procedure works. But when I try to replace the container div it does absolutely nothing.* So which is it: does replacing the container div work, or not?

Comment: Maybe your problem is that the first div must be closed 
 <div class="container"></div>
If the first div is closed, then you can give more information, because I can't see another problem with your code.

Comment: ^the part about closing your div might help. If not, as a control test, try duplicating this to have two distinct containers and have them set each other. Does it still work externally?

Comment: I forgot to copy the closing div, and about the #container beeing replaced, if i try to modify #container to another div that does not contain the links, the replacment works.

Comment: Also, you are using "class" tag, this tag is used to stament a class name of style sheet, then I think you have to use "id" tag.

Comment: `#` -> `id` ; `.` -> `class`

Comment: I didn't notice that. now that i replaced `#` with `.` it all worked. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that instead of class(.) I appended the id tag(#). The solution was to add to the class container an id container. `<div class="container" id="container">`